# Сортировка строк по буквам, цифрам и буквам с цифрами(кодам)

Tags: python-3.x, сортировка

День добрый! Я пытаюсь отсортировать строки, состоящие из букв, цифр и букв вместе с цифрами. Если после записи в файл я удаляю элемент(использую списки), мне выдаёт ошибку list index out of range. Вот мой код:

```
begin = open('begin.txt','r')
digit = open('digit.txt','w')
alpha = open('alpha.txt','w')
code = open('code.txt','w')
countnum,countalpha = 0,0
s = begin.read().split()
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i].isdigit() == True:
        digit.write(s[i])
        countnum += 1
    elif s[i].isalpha() == True:
        alpha.write(s[i])
        countalpha += 1
for j in range(len(s)):
    if s[j].isdigit == True and s[i].isalpha() == True:
        code.write(s[i])
alpha.write('\n')
digit.write('\n')
alpha.write(str(countalpha))
digit.write(str(countnum))
begin.close()
digit.close()
alpha.close()
code.close()
```

Как сделать проверку на буквы и цифры, либо удалить элементы без ошибки?

Comment: Зачем вы заморачиваетесь с индексами, если можете просто сделать `for i in s: if i.isdigit() ...` ?

Comment: В приведённом коде из списков ничего не удаляется, поэтому непонятно в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, нужно распределить строки на числовые, буквенные и смешанные.

```py
begin = open('begin.txt','r')
digit = open('digit.txt','w')
alpha = open('alpha.txt','w')
code = open('code.txt','w')

countnum,countalpha = 0,0
s = begin.read().split()
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i.isdigit() == True: # Если это число пишет в digit.txt
        digit.write(i)
        countnum += 1

    elif i.isalpha() == True: # Если это строка пишет в alpha.txt
        alpha.write(i)
        countalpha += 1

    else: # Если не то и не то, значит смешанная строка
        code.write(s[i])

alpha.write('\n')
digit.write('\n')
alpha.write(str(countalpha))
digit.write(str(countnum))

begin.close()
digit.close()
alpha.close()
code.close()
```

Comment: Выражение if s.isdigit() == True избыточно. Достаточно просто if isdigit() (и if not s.isdigit() для противоположного случая).

Comment: А если ещё будут символы типо точек или скобок, как их отделить можно?

Comment: если еще будут точки и прочее, перед else добавь elif i in ('.', '", ':', '-'):